# Multiple store vendors with own domain per vendor in Magento

Tags: magento, dns, store, vendor

We need to create e-commerce site to be used by multiple person (vendor) that are independent with each other.

Each vendor will have their own account and is independent to other vendors.
Each vendor has independent data to other vendors and each vendor can add,edit,delete their own products, ship own products,send invoice, view their own Sales statistic and other typical vendor functionality.
Each vendor will also have their own domain, not subdomain but their own unique domain.
Each vendor can have their own theme.

My question is, is this possible by default in Magento or we need some magento extension to achieve this? If yes, is Magento platform recommended?

I've read that there Magento can support multiple Stores but im not sure if the requirements i wrote above can be supported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible by default in magento, so you need some extension.
One of the extensions which could fit your needs is: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace.html

It's not free, so if you want to buy it, better to contact the support first and ask them everything what you need, just to be sure that it's right extension for you.

Comment: thanks very much for the suggestion. Very useful for me. I just got a question, is there any Free extension similar to you have given?

Comment: you are welcome! I am not sure for the free extension, but if I find out something, I'll let you know!

Comment: @MarkoKrstic thanks for the information , we are the developer of this product , module works very fine with Magento Enterprise editions as well .

Answer (score 0):

Hi we are the developer of marketplace module for magento extension ( https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html ), also marketplace modules have many addons for shipping and payment ( http://marketplace.webkul.com/add-ons/magento/ ) by which  Each vendor will have independent data to other vendors and each vendor can add,edit,delete their own products, ship own products,send invoice, view their own Sales statistic and other typical vendor functionality .

regarding the subdomain and or separate domain module does not offer shop url in separate domain in base  module it will need further customization of the module .

vendor can manage their profile and collection url with different colors , logo , banner images , social media links and  content .

**PS**  - we are not self promoting our product we are providing correct information so that user must have all the access of the correct data . thanks